# How to consume a RESTful API in Node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, pagination, request

I'm new to Node.js and I'm creating a simple pagination page. The REST API works fine, but consuming it has left me in limbo.
Here is the REST API (other parts have been taken out for brevity)

```
const data = req.query.pageNo;
  const pageNo = 
    (typeof data === 'undefined' || data < 1) ? 1 : parseInt(req.query.pageNo);
  let query = {};
  const total = 10;
  query.skip = (total * pageNo) - total;
  query.limit = total;

  try {
    const totalCount = await Users.countDocuments();
    const pageTotal = Math.ceil(totalCount / total);
    const users = await Users.find({}, {}, query);

    return res.status(200).json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error ', error);
    return res.status(400).send(error)
  };
};
```

When I return the json with just the 'users' object, like so `return res.status(200).json(users);` the page renders correctly, but when I pass in other objects like what I have in the code, it fails. This is how I'm consuming the API:

```
const renderHomepage = (req, res, responseBody) => {
  let message = null;
  if (!(responseBody instanceof Array)) {
    message = 'API lookup error';
    responseBody = [];
  } else {
    if (!responseBody.length) {
      message = 'No users found nearby';
    }
  }

    res.render('users-list', {
      title: 'Home Page',
    users: responseBody,
    message: message
    });
}

const homelist = (req, res) => {
    const path = '/api/users';
    const requestOptions = {
        url: `${apiOptions.server}${path}`,
        method: 'GET',
        json: true,
  };

  request(
    requestOptions,
    (err, {statusCode}, body) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Ther was an error ', err);
      } else if (statusCode === 200 && body.length) {
        renderHomepage(req, res, body);
      } else if (statusCode !== 200 && !body.length) {
        console.log('error ',statusCode);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

I've searched extensively on both here and other resources but none of the solutions quite answers my question. I hope someone could be of help

Comment: responseBody comes from

Comment: Nothing shows on the screen, It keeps loading infintely. responseBody comes from "res.render" function which I've extrapolated in the code.

Comment: `Total Pages` is a varialbe that I'd change; the `json: true` didn't work either

Comment: .. you need res.render or res.send, json or to next() always even on error, else it will hang.

Comment: Please, I just edited my post, showing all relevant code as requested; the result is an infinite loop without rendering any output

Comment: thanks, console log these vars `(err, {statusCode}, body)`, my guess is its not hitting any of your if/else's, most likely error is server side, it wont be status 200, but body has length because you passing back error, so it wont enter into `else if (statusCode !== 200 && !body.length) {`, in renderHomepage your looking for errors again, you might as well do `request(requestOptions,renderHomepage)` and just handle it in one place

Comment: the infinite loop is just server  waiting for a call to res.send etc, as said you need to always respond even on error not just console log else client will hang and feel like an infinite loop

Comment: Thanks so much. I figured it out! The `body` in the `(err, {statusCode}, body)` is an object so I had to use dot notation to call the specifics. Only after logging to the console like you advised did I realize. I'm eternally grateful